# How to conditionally format italics without changing other parameters?

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I am using conditional formatting to color lines based on a priority value in column A, this works fine.

I would like to add another rule that would italicize the lines that match a specific parameter, without changing the background color the previous rules have set.
When I add this rule, the background color is overridden automatically. If I place the rule after the priority rules, I lose the italics.

**Is there a way to change the italicization of a line only, with conditional formatting?**

Comment: I think overlapping is not allowed. I could be wrong. How about using three conditions as a workaround?

Comment: @SeverusSnape That would work, but it would double the number of rules I need... Not exactly a thrilling proposition. Oh well, if that's what's required, that's what it will be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example:**

Rules:

```
Rules                            Format
------------------------------------------------    
Priority is 3; Alcohol           Red    
Priority is 3; Beer              Red and italics
Priority is not 3                None
```

Sheet:

```
A         B
------------
Alcohol   3
Beer      4
Alcohol   5
Beer      3
Alcohol   4
Beer      5
Alcohol   3
Beer      4
Alcohol   5
Beer      3
```

Formula:

> `=AND(SEARCH("Alcohol",$A1),SEARCH("3",$B1))`

> `=AND(SEARCH("Beer",$A1),SEARCH("3",$B1))`

Sample screenshot:

> [image: Screenshot]

Comment: I'll accept this as the answer in a few days, just want to keep it open in case someone else comes along.

Comment: A few days turned out to be a few months, but regardless, answer accepted!